# Functional to inner product in Hilbert triple

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $V \subset H \subset V^*$ is a Hilbert triple, and $f \in V^*$, I cannot represent $f(v) = (e,v)_V$ because we don't identify $V$ with $V^*$. But is it true that
$f(v) = (e,v)_H$ for some $e$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true: the Riesz representation theorem applies to the Hilbert space $V$, regardless of its relation to other spaces.

A sensible way to deal with non-identification is to introduce the *duality map* $J:V\to  V^*$, defined by $J(e)=f$ in your notation. This map is an *isomorphism* of two distinct Hilbert spaces $V$ and $V^*$. This is different from the case of a single (real) Hilbert space, when we think of $J$ as the *identity map*.

By the way, in complex Hilbert spaces $J$ is conjugate-linear, which is a constant source of mild irritation (for me at least).